# Code not working as extension but working otherwise

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

On an MVC view I have the following:

```
@(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))

@(Model.ConvertToJson())
```

The first works fine for a class and for a IPagedList

The second works for a class but not when Model is a IPagedList

The ConvertToJSon extension is the following:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions {
  public static String ConvertToJson<T>(this T obj) {       
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
  }
}
```

Any idea why?

**UPDATE 1**

This is really very strange. When the type of the Model is:

```
PagedList<MyModel>
```

And I use:

```
@Model.ConvertToJson()
```

I get the error:

```
'PagedList<MyModel>' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertToJson'
```

Then I tried the following

```
 @(new { Model = Model }.ConvertToJson()))
```

Now it works ... ConvertToJson is:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions {
  public static String ConvertToJson(this Object obj) {       
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
  }
}
```

Any clue?

**UPDATE 2**

It seems casting works:

```
((Object)Model).ToJson())
```

Strange, isn't it?

Comment: If you change it to `String ConvertToJson(this Object obj)` does it work then? Do you really need to know the type T passed in?

Comment: I have no idea what is going on ... Using Object and T results in the same problem. I now tried with Object. Check the Update ... Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

If you get a runtime exception such as:

> CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

You need to expand the `compilation` section of your main web.config to the following:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

---

The extension works for a model of type `IPagedList`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new PagedList<string>(
            new List<string> { "test1", "test2"}, 1, 2 ));
    }
}

@model PagedList.IPagedList<string>
@(Model.ConvertToJson())
```

This syntax compiles and runs without an error, outputting:

```
["test1","test2"]
```

This also works for `IPagedList<ComplexType>`

```
return View(new PagedList<Test>(new List<Test>
{
    new Test {Id = 1, Name = "test1"},
    new Test {Id = 2, Name = "test2"}     
}, 1, 2));

[{"Id":1,"Name":"test1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"test2"}]
```

Finally, `@Model.ConvertToJson()` is not the same as `@(Model.ConvertToJson())`.

The first will fail at runtime and the second will work.

Make sure you've cleaned and rebuilt your solution.

---

Because it's not the correct extension method syntax.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions {
    public static String ConvertToJson<T>(this T obj) {       
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }
}
```

`this` preceding your Type declaration for your parameter is what tells the compiler that it is an extension method.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: I think I detected the problem. I am using the following PagedList: https://github.com/NickStrupat/PagedList.EntityFramework which allows to use async. When I use this with an extension it seems to fail ... At least is what it seems like

Comment: @Miguel Hmm, I'm not sure how that would be possible.  I added that package and changed to using return View(new List<Test>
            {
                new Test {Id = 1, Name = "test1"},
                new Test {Id = 2, Name = "test2"} 
            }.ToPagedList(1, 2)); and it works just fine.  I'd say you still have an issue that requires cleaning and rebuilding your solution.

Comment: I just updated my code. Do you have any clue what might be wrong? I really have no idea. This does not make any sense.

Comment: @Miguel I responded to your most recent code, since you have another issue.  If this STILL doesn't resolve it, it would seem that the code you've pasted is not the verbatim code that is giving you trouble.